# Is it possible to send a value using js without map form refresh?

Tags: javascript, forms, return-value

I have implemented search by map function on my web-site. The map have some divisions that are clickable and send a value to the controller.

```
<form name="myform" action="index.php?option=com&amp;task=seacrh_by_map" method="post">
<dd id="imgDI">
<a id="DI" href="javascript:getvalue('DI')" 
</a>
</dd>
<dd id="imgDII">
<a id="DI" href="javascript:getvalue('DII')" 
</a>
</dd>
<input type="hidden" name="my_value" value="" />    
</form>


<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function getvalue (my_value)
{
document.myform.my_value.value = my_value;
document.myform.submit() ;
}
-->
</script>
```

After sending this form, the controller gives an answer (results of search) and the map returns to its original position. Is there a way to prevent that? The map should show the division that was chosen. Is there a way to send a value to controller using js without map form refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AJAX and JSON for this

AJAX = a method of retrieving resources asynchronously via HTTP using JavaScript
JSON = stands for JavaScript Object Notation

Simple Example is [Here](http://www.jquery4u.com/json/ajaxjquery-getjson-simple/#.T8SO6LBo3Zc)

AJAX stands for asynchronous JavaScript and XML, a scary-sounding mix
of technologies, but don’t let the buzzwords scare you. Think of AJAX as a
programming technique that combines several technologies. And remember,
you’re in luck because [jQuery simplifies AJAX](http://www.jquery4u.com/json/ajaxjquery-getjson-simple/#.T8SO6LBo3Zc) for you.